# Using ttf font file in iTextSharp Blazor .net 6

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, blazor, itext

Im trying to use custom ttf file in iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core but getting error

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Font 'La Belle Aurore' with
> 'Cp1252' is not recognized.

```
var font = BaseFont.CreateFont("La Belle Aurore", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED, BaseFont.NOT_CACHED, await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync($"/fonts/LaBelleAurore-Regular.ttf"), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Font name has to end with .ttf

```
var font = BaseFont.CreateFont("LaBelleAurore-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED, BaseFont.NOT_CACHED, await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync($"/fonts/LaBelleAurore-Regular.ttf"), null);
```